# Setting up Environment Variables for Azure ABP.IO React Mobile App

Tags: reactjs, azure, abp

I have created and deployed the abp.io project to Azure. I have created the DB and Web app successfully.

Now I exploring the React mobile front end. I am attempting to point the React app at localhost or the Azure server.

I have set the environment variables 'apiUrl' and 'issuer' to my IP and my azure website based on the documentation(https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Getting-Started-React-Native) and get the same error shown below.

Localhost Error:

```
Network Error

The above error occurred in task fetchAppConfig
    created by takeLatest(app/fetchAppConfigAsync, fetchAppConfig)
    created by _callee
    created by rootSaga
Tasks cancelled due to error:
takeLatest(app/fetchAppConfigAsync, fetchAppConfig)
takeLatest(app/setLanguageAsync, setLanguage)
takeLatest(app/logoutAsync, logout)
```

Azure Error:

```
Request failed with status code 500
- node_modules\axios\lib\core\createError.js:15:17 in createError
- node_modules\axios\lib\core\settle.js:16:9 in settle
- node_modules\axios\lib\adapters\xhr.js:53:6 in handleLoad
- node_modules\event-target-shim\dist\event-target-shim.js:818:20 in EventTarget.prototype.dispatchEvent
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Network\XMLHttpRequest.js:592:4 in setReadyState
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Network\XMLHttpRequest.js:395:6 in __didCompleteResponse   
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\vendor\emitter\EventEmitter.js:189:10 in emit
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:416:4 in __callFunction
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:109:6 in __guard$argument_0  
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:364:10 in __guard
- node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:108:4 in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
* [native code]:null in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue

The above error occurred in task fetchAppConfig
    created by takeLatest(app/fetchAppConfigAsync, fetchAppConfig)
    created by _callee
    created by rootSaga
Tasks cancelled due to error:
takeLatest(app/fetchAppConfigAsync, fetchAppConfig)
takeLatest(app/setLanguageAsync, setLanguage)
takeLatest(app/logoutAsync, logout)

Animated: `useNativeDriver` was not specified. This is a required option and must be explicitly set to `true` or `false`
.
.
.
* [native code]:null in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
```

Comment: I found a simillar issue on the abp support with no solution. https://support.abp.io/QA/Questions/682/fetchAppConfig-error-in-react-native-application

Comment: > React Native application does not trust the auto-generated .NET HTTPS certificate. You should use HTTP during the development.

A React Native application running on an Android emulator or a physical phone can not connect to the backend on localhost.
Please make sure that run the backend on the **local IP address** and **HTTP**. Then, you should update the URLs in Environment.js accordingly.
If you're still seeing errors after applying the configuration I mentioned above, please share the backend error logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem And I did the following :

1. Using HTTP, not HTTPS [I think this may solve your problem with azure]
2. Using [Conveyor](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vs-publisher-1448185.ConveyorbyKeyoti) to get a URL for my local web app instead of using localhost as the localhost is not defined for the mobile